# What is the difference between wildcard/asterisk import and named import while importing a json file in Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, import, vuejs2

Consider the following markup:

```
<template>
  <p
  v-for="experience of pastExperience"
  v-bind:key="experience.experienceID"
  >
    ID: {{ experience.experienceID }}
  </p>
</template>
```

In the <script> section:

1. Using wildcard import:

```
import * as pastExperience from 'filePath';

export default {
  name: "WorkHistory",
  data() {
    return {
      pastExperience: pastExperience,
    };
  },
};
```

2. Using named import:

```
import pastExperience from 'filePath';

export default {
  name: "WorkHistory",
  data() {
    return {
      pastExperience: pastExperience,
    };
  },
};
```

The outputs are as follows:

1. Using method #1:
   [image: Using method #1]
2. Using method #2:
   [image: Using method #2]

For reference, here is the basic structure of the json file:

```
[
  {
    "experienceID": 0,
    "companyName": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "experienceID": 1,
    "companyName: "DEF"
  }
]
```

Why are two extra paragraphs rendered when I import the json file via the wildcard method? What happens exactly in Vue v2 behind the scenes which causes this behaviour?

Comment: I'm surprised not to be able to find a previous question on this, it's a point of confusion for many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, they do entirely different things.

`import * as x from "./mod.js";` imports a *module namespace object* for the `mod.js` module, which is a synthetically-generated object containing properties for all of the module's named exports, if any, and a `default` property for the default export, if any.

`import x from "./mod.js";` **only** imports the default export of the `mod.js` module, if any, not its named exports.

But some modules may be defined such that the default export is an object with properties for all of the named exports, and so in that case they can *seem* very much the same, but they still aren't: real exports are *live* bindings, but exporting an object with properties for the named exports as the default export won't update those properties if they change in the source module. But in modules defined in that dual way, the exports are usually static anyway.

Consider `mod.js`:

```
export let a = 42;
export default function example() {
    console.log("Example");
}
```

Using `import * as x from "./mod.js"` would make `x` a reference to the module namespace object for the module, with the properties `a` (the number 42, initially) and `default` (the `example` function:

```
import * as x from "./mod.js";
console.log(x.a); // Logs 42
x.default(); // Logs "Example"
```

In contrast, `import x from "./mod.js";` would make `x` a live binding to the `example` function.

```
import x from "./mod.js";
x(); // Logs "Example"
```

But if the module is defined in that dual way, both with named exports and a default exported module, like this:

```
export let a = 42;
export function example() {
    console.log("Example");
}
export default {
    a,
    example
};
```

Then `import * as x from "./dual.js";` would give us a module namespace object with `a`, `example`, and `default` properties, and `import x from "./dual.js";` would give us an object (not the module namespace object) with `a` and `example` properties, which is of course very similar. The difference is that the former will see changes to `a` if any are made, and the latter won't.

Comment: 'Using import * as x from "./mod.js" would make x a reference to the module namespace object for the module' cleared things up. So, even if it is being imported as a module namespace object when using wildcard, why is it still able to display the IDs? As per my understanding, they should not be displayed since to get the correct object inside the array, we would need to use "pastExperience.moduleValues" (or whatever the key of that namespace object is) instead of "pastExperience" in "v-for" attribute. Is there some fallback method on which Vue/JS relies upon to get around errors like this one?

Comment: @chess_madridista - That's what I'm talking about in the paragraph starting *"But some modules may be defined such that the default export..."* and with my `dual.js` example.